# Edit API Dropdown

Tags: forms, eloquent, laravel-8, edit

I populated the country list in my select option and  when I click on country in user menu data save successfully and afterward while updating the user field the country name is not showing/or the old list from api loads this happens in laravel 08

Code to populate select option

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        
            const selectDrop = document.querySelector('#countries');
            // const selectDrop = document.getElementById('countries');
        
        
            fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all').then(res => {
              return res.json();
            }).then(data => {
            let output = "";
              data.forEach(country => {
                console.log(country.name.common)
                output += `<option value="${country.name.common}">${country.name.common}</option>`;
              })
        
            selectDrop.innerHTML = output;
        
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            })
          });
```

here is my controller

```
    public function update(Request $request){
                try{
            $user= User::data_update($request);
            return view ('profile_edit', ['user'=>$user]);
                }catch (\Exception $exception){
                    return $exception;
                }
            }
```

here is my model

```
    public static function data_update($user1)
        {
                $user = self::user_data();
                $user->name = $user1['name'];
                $user->email = $user1['email'];
                $user->phone = $user1['phone'];
                $user->gender = $user1['gender'];
                $user->country = $user1['country'];
                $status = $user->save();
                return $user;
    
    }
```

here is my blade

```
    <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
        <select id="countries"  name="country">
            <option value="{{$user->country}}" selected ></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is `$user = self::user_data();`

Comment: This is function to get the value of user by id

Comment: Can you please post this `user_data()` function as well to better understand what's going on. And about your question can you please elaborate more about exactly what's happening?

Comment: By reading your question I came to a conclusion that your country is updating via dropdown, but its not rendering the updated country in dropdown. Which is due to your JavaScript rendering code. In your JS, you instructed to just populate the dropdown. You didn't instruct it to show the user's selected country. Maybe that's the reason you can't see the updated value and only the whole API country names list.

Comment: public static function user_data()
    {
        $user = self::where('id', Auth::id())->first();
        return $user;
    }

Comment: and yes you figured out correct now what to do with Js code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).